# erlang suppressing output from mnesia

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I want to suppress the "informational" output from mnesia.

I.e. when I do

```
mnesia:load_textfile("foo.txt").
```

I get, on stdout:

```
New table foo
New table bar
```

I still want to keep all warnings and error on stdout. This is the only thing I want to redirect or disable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to do this. Those messages are emitted unconditionally via `io:format` calls from within the [`mnesia` source code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/mnesia/src/mnesia_text.erl#L96), and the `mnesia` functions don't provide any options to control whether the messages are emitted or not.

Comment: Thanks! Then I can stop looking.